# Facebook 2.6 Open Graph no email

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using PHP SDk to access user information in FB for a login process. I have a test app setup and it all works fine, I get the below response (including the email):

```
bject(Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode) {
[protected] graphObjectMap => array()
[protected] items => array(
    'id' => 'XXXXX',
    'email' => 'strXXXXXXX@gmail.com',
    'currency' => object(Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode) {
        [protected] graphObjectMap => array()
        [protected] items => array(
            'currency_offset' => (int) 100,
            'usd_exchange' => (float) 1.24596885,
            'usd_exchange_inverse' => (float) 0.802588283,
            'user_currency' => 'GBP'
        )
    },
    'first_name' => 'XXX',
    'last_name' => 'XXX',
    'picture' => object(Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode) {
        [protected] graphObjectMap => array()
        [protected] items => array(
            'is_silhouette' => false,
            'url' => 'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/XXXXXX'
        )
    }
)
```

}

If I then switch to the live app the response doesnt have the email:

```
object(Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode) {
[protected] graphObjectMap => array()
[protected] items => array(
    'id' => 'XXXXX',
    'currency' => object(Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode) {
        [protected] graphObjectMap => array()
        [protected] items => array(
            'currency_offset' => (int) 100,
            'usd_exchange' => (float) 1.24596885,
            'usd_exchange_inverse' => (float) 0.802588283,
            'user_currency' => 'GBP'
        )
    },
    'first_name' => 'XXXX',
    'last_name' => 'XXXX',
    'picture' => object(Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode) {
        [protected] graphObjectMap => array()
        [protected] items => array(
            'is_silhouette' => false,
            'url' => 'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/XXXXXXXX'
        )
    }
)
```

}

All I have changed is the app ID and secret. Any ideas?

Comment: Did the user grant the necessary permission to your app …?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access e-mail, your app needs to explicitly ask for e-mail when it requests permissions from the user (which I suspect you set up at the start).

If you haven't been granted that permission by the user themselves, you also won't be able to access it.

Per Facebook's documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-email

> email
>
> Provides access to the person's primary email address via the email property on the user object.
>
> Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty.